# Attribute that excludes method from the class attribute

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF service with a security attribute that's applicable only for a class. Is there a built-in .NET attribute or can I create an attribute that marks the method as 'excluded' where I could put in a method so that the class attribute won't be applied? I don't have access to the security attribute so I can't do any modifications with it. I can obviously create a separate class for the method, but it will involve a lot of refactoring.

```
[SecuredService] // I don't have access to this custom attribute
public class MyClass
{
   [DoNotApplySecuredService]//is there a built in attribute like this?
   public void MyMethod(){...}
}
```

Comment: What is the `[SecuredService]` attribute?  That isn't built into .Net.

Comment: @Amy SecuredService is our custom attribute. I was asking if there is a built in attribute for a method that will override it.

Comment: No, there isn't a built in attribute that can override one you wrote.